# Searching for specific row combinations

Tags: python, csv

I am using the csv writer/reader library.  Given a csv example of:

```
a,x,1
a,y,1
b,z,y
a,c,1
a,x,5
b,x,y
```

How can I have python search for and return where a combination of row[0], row[2] occurs more than once? i.e. it should return a,x,1 + a,y,1 + a,c,1 as one match and b,z,y + b,x,y as another match.

I understand how to have python open the text file and then have it compare the current line to the previous line to see if it matches.  However matches could obviously be anywhere in the file I'm not sure how to do that bit.

THanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "a combination of row[0], row[2] occurs more than once?" Your example doesn't quite make sense to me. why is 'b,z,y + b,x,y' a match?

Comment: create a `dict` (hint: use `collections.defaultdict`) where keys are `tuple` of first and third element and values will be lists. parse the csv file and populate the `dict` by adding each row to leist for respective key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` dictionary and use tuples of `(first, last)` as keys and lists of rows where the first and last elements are `(first, last)` as values:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for d in reader:
        result[(d[0], d[-1])].append(d)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
 {
  ('a', '1'): [['a', 'x', '1'], ['a', 'y', '1'], ['a', 'c', '1']],
  ('b', 'y'): [['b', 'z', 'y'], ['b', 'x', 'y']],
  ('a', '5'): [['a', 'x', '5']]
 }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./xxx.csv', header=None, names=['c1','c2','c3'])
g = df.groupby(by=['c1','c3']).filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).groupby(by=['c1','c3'])
d = {k:v.values.tolist() for k,v in dict(list(g)).items()}
```

*Output*

```
d
{('a', '1'): [['a', 'x', '1'], ['a', 'y', '1'], ['a', 'c', '1']],
 ('b', 'y'): [['b', 'z', 'y'], ['b', 'x', 'y']]}
```